# Access Denied when executing Process.Start from Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I'm trying to run a process from the service as another user.

```
Process.Start(applicationPath, params, account, SecureStringPassword, "");
```

A service is running under the "Local System" account.

The `account` parameter is a string like "WORKSTATION6\Tester". This user is a member of the Administrators group.

"Application Path" refers to Program Files, so every user can read from it.

But I have an "Access Denied" Exception every time I try to start the process. What can you advice?

Comment: Have you tried watching it in [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)? That might show you exactly what it can't access. But it sounds like the user switching might be the problem though.

Comment: I tried ProcMon, but it show nothing useful for me. There is no errors at the log.  

And what about user-switching problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example of how to use Process.Start on the SecureString page. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=VS.90).aspx#Y682](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=VS.90%29.aspx#Y682)

I think what you need to do is put the domain of your user account in the last parameter like this:

```
Process.Start(applicationPath, params, "Tester", SecureStringPassword, "WORKSTATION6");
```

Comment: I have the same problem... already tried to call a .bat file, use WMI, impersonation, but no success. Any update @E-Max?